# better way of coding this jquery

Tags: jquery, optimization

So far this jquery code works for what I want it to do.  Basically when a user click on an image it fades out these Divs and then fades in the one that needs to show:

```
$('.brother').click(function() {
        $("#mitsu-gallery:visible, .mitsu-tag:visible, #taki-gallery:visible, .taki-    tag:visible").fadeOut("slow", function() {
             $("#brother-gallery, .brother-tag").fadeIn("slow");
        });
     });
```

But what I am wondering if there is a better way to do this instead of listing all the Divs that I want to hide?  Or is this just the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you have the option of changing the HTML, use a class or custom attribute for each element you want to hide.

Answer (score 3):

Use one class on all the `DIVs` you want to hide.

E.g.

```
<div id="mitsu-gallery" class="hideme">Content</div>
```

And

```
$('.hideme').fadeOut(blah, blah);
```

**EDIT:**

After reviewing [your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ultraloveninja/AmNyJ/5/), here is your best option:

```
$('.control').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var field = $(this).data('field');
    $('.hider:visible').fadeOut("slow", function () {
        $('#' + field + '-gallery, #' + field + '-tag').fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

**Please** also review the HTML and CSS changes on this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/matthewbj/GBYSc/)

Comment: Ah.  That would work if it was one or the other.  But if one link is clicked how do I hide all the others but that one that I am trying to show since I'll prolly have five Div's in total that will be there, but if one link is clicked how does it know which ones to hide and which one to show?

Comment: @user16613 It would be hard to say without seeing your HTML

Comment: @MJB This is it in a nutshell:

`
<div id="brother-gallery">Content</div>
<div id="mitsu-gallery">Content</div>
<div id="taki-gallery">Content</div>

<div id="brother-tag">Tagline</div>
<div id="mitsu-tag">Tagline</div>
<div id="taki-tag">Tagline</div>

`

Basically, the brother-gallery and the brother-tag Divs are shown by default.  Then when a user clicks on the Mitsu image it will hide all other showing divs, which could be either the brother-gallery and tag or the taki-gallery and tag, and display the mitsu gallery and tag.

Comment: Sorry, it saved my comment before I could format the markdown.

Comment: That would be better, right?  Here ya go: http://jsfiddle.net/ultraloveninja/AmNyJ/5/